# Django urlconf issue (know there has to be a simple answer)

Tags: python, django, web, urlconf

Hi I am a beginner with django and all I have left to deploy the site is a stupid url conf problem. I have a simple site with 5 pages that are `home,contact,about,reasons, and benefits`. Simple right, url conf will be `(r'^home/$',index)`, and as follows for the rest of the pages. Here is the problem when I go to the home page `/home/` fine. Now go to any other page on the navigation like `/reasons/` or `/about/`,they dont get called like that, instead get called `/home/reasons/` or `/home/about/`. Even more so if from `/home/about/` I click back to home the call is `/home/about/home`. As you see this goes on forever. How can it be where every request to a page is a simple `/about/` or `/contact/` instead of `/home/contact or /home/about`.

I had defined one that went `/home/contact/home/home/about/reasons/home` I cant possibly put all those in urlconf

Note: this is all being ran on django dev server

Comment: Whats your urls.py and template to put url?

Comment: Hi CJ, can you post the contents of your urls.py? It will be easier for people to debug it if we can see it.

Comment: are you saying that a call to `reverse()` is returning `/home/contact/home/home/about/reasons/home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your urls look like this:

```
(r'^home/$', myapp.views.index)
```

then use it in template as:

```
<a href="{% url myapp.views.index %}>some text</a>
```

to avoid wrong interpretation. Django will do the rest.

For Django 1.5 use

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.index' %}>some text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in your templates you're using absolute URLs, so instead of

```
<a href="contacts">Contacts</a>
```

it should be

```
<a href="/contacts/">Contacts</a>
```

and there is **no** [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) in your template

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're links on your page look like

```
<a href="/home/">...</a> <-- this will take you to home page
```

and NOT

```
<a href="home/">...</a> <-- this will take you to {current_url}/home/
```